# Git clone causes: "Cannot get remote repository information."

Tags: git, github, clone

When I `ssh -v git@github.com`, it authenticates fine.

However, when I `git clone https://github.com/myusername/project.git` I get:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/webapps/myproject/.git/
Cannot get remote repository information.
Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?
```

I've triple checked that I'm entering the url correctly.  Also, it doesn't matter whether I use the git:// vs http:// protocol.  Any ideas?

Comment: its not part of the command, see the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try actually using the SSH protocol (which is also what happens if you don't specify a protocol):

```
git clone git@github.com:username/project.git
```

Also double-check that you're typing the username and project correctly (and that you've forked the repository if you're trying to clone an existing project).

Answer (score 4):

`git clone git://github.com/myusername/project.git`

Should help.